# Initialization by null pointer constant: which behaviour is correct?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, language-lawyer

```
int main() {
    const int x = 0;
    int* y = x;   // line 3
    int* z = x+x; // line 4
}
```

Quoth the standard (C++11 §4.10/1)

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
>   zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; ...

There are four possibilities:

1. Line 4 is OK, but line 3 isn't. This is because `x` and `x+x` are both constant expressions that evaluate to 0, but only `x+x` is a prvalue. It appears that gcc takes this interpretation ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6df2b4b41e849f14))
2. Lines 3 and 4 are both OK. Although `x` is an lvalue, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied, giving a prvalue constant expression equal to 0. The clang on my system (clang-3.0) accepts both lines 3 and 4.
3. Lines 3 and 4 are both not OK. clang-3.4 errors on both lines ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95d790bb50e1bda4)).
4. Line 3 is OK, but line 4 isn't. (Included for the sake of completeness even though no compiler I tried exhibits this behaviour.)

Who is right? Does it depend on which version of the standard we are considering?

Comment: Outside of "Who is right" regarding (3) or (4), an arguably equally compelling question is, who would actually do *either*, and *why*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wording in the standard changed as a result of [DR 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903). The new wording is

> A null pointer constant is an *integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero* or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Issue 903 involves a curious corner case where it is impossible to produce the "correct" overload resolution in certain cases where a template parameter is a (possibly 0) integer constant.

Apparently a number of possible resolutions were considered, but

> There was a strong consensus among the CWG that only the literal 0 should be considered a null pointer constant, not any arbitrary zero-valued constant expression as is currently specified.

So, yes, it depends on whether the compiler has implemented the resolution to DR 903 or not.